# Matching Regex with special characters repeated

Tags: regex

have a test string .

1. consists of 8 digits.
2. must have `---`, `-`, `.` or `:` separator such that string  gets divided in  parts, with each part having exactly two digits.
3. string must have exactly one kind of separator.
4. Separators must have integers on both sides

**i am not able to met 3rd condition**

My answer : 
`^(\d{2}(([-]{3})|.|:|-)){3}(\d){2}$`

Example: 
1. `11---11---11---11`
2. `11:11:11:11`

Please help .

Comment: Don't know what language you're using, but try escaping the special chars in your regexp (\., \:, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the requirements translate to the string having the form `##:##:##:##`, i.e. two numbers, following by separator, etc.

You can use patterns for each separator type along with an alternation to include all four separator types:

```
^(?:\d{2}---\d{2}---\d{2}---\d{2})|
 (?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})|
 (?:\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})|
 (?:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$
```

I broke the regex up into multiple lines for readability.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

This regex could be simplified to this:

```
^(?:\d{2}---){3}\d{2}|(?:\d{2}-){3}\d{2}|(?:\d{2}:){3}\d{2}|(?:\d{2}\.){3}\d{2}$
```

But I actually prefer the longer open form because it is easier to read.

Comment: it is lengthy regex.. any shorter expression where we dont have to repeat 4 times

Answer (score 0):

More Simpliefied answer : 
^(?:\d{2}(-){3}){3}\d{2}|(?:\d{2}-){3}\d{2}|(?:\d{2}:){3}\d{2}|(?:\d{2}.){3}\d{2}$